# How to fix the bottom navigation bar on all screens. Flutter

Tags: flutter-bottomnavigation

tell me how to create a bottom nav bar that will be displayed on all screens?

I tried persistent_bottom_nav_bar, but I do not know how to set my design, I also used cupertino tabbar, but it also does not allow me to create my own design. I need to pass items not to BottomNavBarItems, but to a container. My task is to create a bottom nav bar that will be displayed on all screens, the upper corners should be rounded, the background color under the icon and title should also change when selected. In general, I need to use container instead of bottomNavBarItems. If you know how to set your design in the cupertino tab bar or in the persistent package, then please tell us!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).